# Using a different dataset for ticks with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a question concerning matplotblib in Python. I am working with a dataset, which has 30 sessions. In each session there are 0 to 5 runs. I have created a plot, which displays the values of each run over the run. So the runs go from 0-200. However, I need the ticks to be resetted when a new run starts. So instead of 0-200, I want 0,1,2,3...0,1,2...0,1,2,3,4,5. The graph as it is however, is not supposed to change. Do you have any idea how this would be possible?

The code:

```
for ses in range(len(all_runs)):
        if len(all_runs[ses]) > 0:
            plt.plot(xval[ses],all_runs[ses],'.-',color='tab:blue')
```

Comment: Hi Lea, can you post a sample of the code you've tried so far?

Comment: Unfortunately, the code contains a lot of data and since I am working with confidential patient data this is not really possible.

Comment: To create a [minimal viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) some toy data and only the part of the code that is necessary to reproduce the issue would be the most valuable, also when code and data wouldn't be confidential.  Without some concrete data and code it is hard to grasp the question well. How is your data organized? What do you mean by 0 to 5 runs? Some sessions with 0 runs and some with more runs? Your example ends with "0,1,3,4,5", is the "2" left out intentionally?

Comment: So the ses is short for sessions and the rus are in the list all_runs. I hope it makes more sense now!

Comment: An example for xval: [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]), array([11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]), ....

Comment: all_runs is basically the according y-value, so it is the same number of lists with the same length as the arrays of xval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, this is how it would work. Optionally, the minor ticks could indicate the sessions.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xval = [np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), np.array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]), np.array([11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17])]
all_runs = [np.random.randint(1, 10, len(xv)) for xv in xval]
total_len = sum([len(xv) for xv in xval])

for ses in range(len(all_runs)):
    if len(all_runs[ses]) > 0:
        plt.plot(xval[ses], all_runs[ses], '.-', color='tab:blue')
        # if ses > 0:
        #    plt.axvline(xval[ses][0] - 0.5, ls=':', lw=1, color='purple')
plt.xticks(range(total_len), [i for xv in xval for i in range(len(xv))])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks([xv[0] + 0.1 for xv in xval if len(xv) > 0], minor=True)
ax.set_xticklabels([f'session {i}' for i, xv in enumerate(xval) if len(xv) > 0], minor=True)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='minor', length=0, pad=18)
for tick in ax.xaxis.get_minor_ticks():
    tick.label1.set_horizontalalignment('left')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `labels` argument to `plt.xticks()`, specifying the repeating tick labels, without changing the plotted data. For example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 5  # number of ticks per run
r = 3  # number of runs

# sample plot
plt.plot(list(range(n * r)))
plt.xticks(list(range(n * r)))

# set repeating tick labels
ticks = list(plt.xticks()[0])
plt.xticks(ticks, labels = ticks[:n] * r);
```

[image: sample plot]